# Set values in DataFrame together for specific indices and specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to set values in DataFrame for a set of indices and columns at the same time, but I am getting None values.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.DataFrame({0: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1: ['e', 'f', 'g']})
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [i for i in range(10)], 'top1': [i*2 for i in range(10)], 'top2': [i*3 for i in range(10)]})
at_index = np.array([0,1,2])

### I tried all of those ways but none of them worked.
data.loc[at_index, ["top1", "top2"]] = results
# data[["top1", "top2"]].iloc[at_index] = results
# data.iloc[at_index][["top1", "top2"]] = results
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that the column name of `results` and target `top1`, `top2` are not the same. You can try assign numpy array

```py
data.loc[at_index, ["top1", "top2"]] = results.values # or results.to_numpy()
```

```
print(data)

   id top1 top2
0   0    a    e
1   1    b    f
2   2    c    g
3   3    6    9
4   4    8   12
5   5   10   15
6   6   12   18
7   7   14   21
8   8   16   24
9   9   18   27
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it will be considered as a NumPy array without `values`.

Comment: Or make sure the column names of your results dataframe matches the target dataframe.